# Connect pfsense and VPC in AWS by ipsec tunnel

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services, ipsec, pfsense

I'm trying to connect my pfsense box with AWS VPC by ipsec tunnel. I read couple of tutorials and all looks good. But ... Yes, always there is some but. When only one person is working then all is good. Even when I have more then 1 session, but from the same PC. When somebody else connect in meantime, both session stuck. VPN Tunnel is still connect and even reconnect doesn't help.

I wish to use Netgate AWS Wizard, but I'm using pfsense downloaded from net not bought from the their store.

Do you have any idea why? Thank you for any help and answer.